# passing form data to authenticator

Tags: cakephp, authenticator

In my cakephp 5 application -> src/Application.php I configured a form authenticator and a (dummy) identificator:

```
$service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form');
$service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Callback', [
   'callback' => function($data) {
           $result['username'] = $data['username'];
           if (!empty($result)) {
            return new Result($result, Result::SUCCESS);
           }

           return new Result(
                null,
                Result::FAILURE_OTHER,
                ['message' => 'unknown user.']);

           return NULL;
           }
        ]);
```

Passing of username and password from the login form works, the authentification itself also, but I get no identificator, inside the Users controller I get NULL for

```
$this->Authentication->getIdentity());
```

Maybe the $result object doesn't contain the right data?

Thanks,
Christoph

Comment: You don't directly get anything from other authenticators, authenticators are independent of each other, and should one succeed, then the authenticator chain will stop. Data sent from the frontend can be found in the request object, for example in `$request->getQueryParams()` for `GET` data or `$request->getParsedBody()` for `POST` data.

Comment: Ok, so I have to use the callback authenticator, there I get the data from the form via variable $data.

Comment: I changed the logic, now I get no identificator.